# Can CMake automatically handle addition of -ffat-lto-objects depending on downstream dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake, lto

As you may know GCC can produce fat or thin LTO objects, fat are needed if you will **not** be using the resulting object with LTO linking.
I have a project with hundreds of targets, it is hard to track which libraries need to be built as fat lto and which ones do not.

Is there some way in CMake to conditionally add -ffat-lto-objects  to build of a library only if it is used in non LTO linking?

Comment: CMake build system is Turing complete so any programmable effect is possible to gain. So answer is yes. Like all programmable systems it lacks big red button of "do what I want". Any effect can be harder or easier to gain depending on rest of the pile of garbage that you already have there.